# Размер дискового пространства на кластере hadoop hdfs

Tags: hadoop

Подскажите, пож-та, Каким образом я могу определить размера дискового пространства как общего , так и свободного на кластере hadoop (hdfs) ?

Answer (score 0):

В этом поможет следующая команда:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

Если сведения о каждой ноде в кластере не интересуют, то можно вывести только первые строки:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report | head -10
```

В результате можно увидеть как общий размер кластера, так и то, сколько места занято:

```
Configured Capacity: 1043769777344512 (949.30 TB)
Present Capacity: 921867125213189 (838.43 TB)
DFS Remaining: 921288324896924 (837.91 TB)
DFS Used: 578800316265 (539.05 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.06%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
```